# Google LicensingService crash on Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio

When my app checks for obb expansion file it crashes, giving the following error:

```
Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService } - Error.
```

I know that this exact issue was a problem on Android 5.0+ and it was solved as follows:
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1674

However, this is happening again on android 6.0+ now. And that fix is not working for 6.0+.

Any idea how to solve this?